# Deploy Spring Boot to Wildfly 10

Tags: java, spring-mvc, wildfly, wildfly-10

Has anyone try to deploy an springboot application to wildfly 10 succesfully? i have look for examples but i only found for wildfly 8.2

This is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ServereurekaApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServereurekaApplication.class, args);
}
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ServereurekaApplication.class);
}
}
```

this is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.servereureka</groupId>
<artifactId>servereureka</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>servereureka</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I always get this error:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/servereureka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/servereureka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig; Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;"}}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Exclude jaxrs subsystem using jboss-deployment-structure.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, i just have to add that file in webapp\WEB-INF

Answer (score 1):

You dependencies in the pom.xml need to be like this:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And extends SpringBootServletInitializer in your Application.java file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

You basically ne
I hope this helps